# Configure connection pool on StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I am starting to use StackExchange.Redis as my c# redis client.

the first thing i tried to do was to set the connection pool on StackExchange, after some internet search and checking the code i could not find it.

is it possible to set the number of open connection on this client or at least control it?

Comment: AFAIK SE.Redis does multiplexing on a single connection and, hence, doesn't do connection pooling (see here: https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md), but I may be wrong. Perhaps Marc could straighten this out...

Comment: The github page mentioned in the above comment is moved to https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/docs/PipelinesMultiplexers.md